# Edit fields of outgoing HTTP request headers in C#

Tags: c#, http

Is it possible to do the same thing that Tamper Data does but within a C# program? Like if I give the program a session ID and I want that session ID inserted in every cookie sent into outgoing HTTP request to a certain site? I want to be able to stop outgoing HTTP requests and edit them as I like and then let them go.

Is it possible or do I need to create an extension for my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use a third party program, I would suggest you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which is available for free.

To automate an action, you could create a .Net dll with your logic and then load it in Fiddler, or write a simple script in JScpript which will be probably easy if your logic is quite simple.

What you need is to add a rule as explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Extend-Fiddler/AddRules) in the manual.

If you decide to use JScript, you could find some [examples](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) in the manual.

To set the cookie you could do something similar to this in **OnBeforeRequest**:

```
oSession.oRequest["Cookie"] = (oSession.oRequest["Cookie"] + ";SessionID=YOUR_SESSION_ID");
```

Comment: Yeah I just need to do what Tamper Data does but in an automatized way so I don't have to edit every packet by hand, I will take a look at Fiddler

Comment: Ty very much for all the help it does exactly what I wanted! Also, how can I remove a field from the cookie? Like now I have multiple SessionID fields, so I wanted to remove the original and put the edited one.

Comment: Do you have other fields you need to preserve in the cookie? otherwise you could replace it completely with oSession.oRequest["Cookie"] = "SessionID=YOUR_SESSION_ID";

Comment: yeah there are quite a lot of fileds in the cookie, but I could then replace every single one of them with the same method is use now for the SessionID.